# Highcharts : Real time updating spline chart sets y-axis data to zero

Tags: javascript, dynamic, highcharts, updates, spline

I am trying to display a set of dynamic data in a spline type chart using highcharts.

My spline type line chart has 4 series of data that needs to update through a service call. Service returns an array of data such as [0.345, 0.465, 0, 0.453] and I want to update y value of each series with the respective value in the array.

But my chart does not draw the data as expected. Even if I receive different values for y, in the chart it always displays it as 0.

This is my source code. Greatly appreciate  if someone could help me figure out the issue in this or a give solution to this problem.

```js
function drawHighChart() {
  hchart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
      type: 'spline',
      animation: Highcharts.svg,
      marginRight: 10,
    },

    time: {
      useUTC: false
    },

    title: {
      text: 'Audio Analytics'
    },

    xAxis: {
      tickInterval: 1,
    },

    yAxis: {
      title: {
        text: 'Prediction'
      },
      min: 0,
      max: 1,
      tickInterval: 0.5,
      plotLines: [{
        value: 0,
        width: 1,
        color: '#808080'
      }]
    },

    tooltip: {
      headerFormat: '<b>{series.name}</b><br/>',
      pointFormat: '{point.x:%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S}<br/>{point.y:.2f}'
    },

    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },

    exporting: {
      enabled: false
    },

    /* Initially I'm setting some hardcoded values for each series.*/
    
    series: [{
      name: 'Calm',
      data: [0.43934, 0.52503, 0.57177, 0.69658, 0.97031, 0.119931, 0.137133]
    }, {
      name: 'Happy',
      data: [0.24916, 0.24064, 0.29742, 0.0000, 0.32490, 0.0000, 0.38121]
    }, {
      name: 'Angry',
      data: [0.11744, 0.17722, 0.16005, 0.19771, 0.20185, 0.24377, 0.32147]
    }, {
      name: 'Disgust',
      data: [0.7988, 0.15112, null, 0.22452, 0.34400, null, 0.34227]
    }],

  });
}
```

Now when I call `drawHighChart()` at the windows onload this is what it outputs.

[image]

Now from here, I need to update each series dynamically as service returns a data array.

This is my function that updates the chart dynamically every time the service returns a response. Every time I call this fucntion, I pass a data array constructed from the response data.

```js
initiVal = 7; //This is a gloabl variable that increases x-axis value from 7.

function updateHighChart(dataArray) {
  var series = hchart.series[0];
  var series1 = hchart.series[1];
  var series2 = hchart.series[2];
  var series3 = hchart.series[3];
  var x = initiVal;
  
  y = dataArray[0];
  y1 = dataArray[1];
  y2 = dataArray[2];
  y3 = dataArray[3];
  console.log("dataArray: " + dataArray);
  
  series.addPoint([x, y], true, true);
  series1.addPoint([x, y1], true, true);
  series2.addPoint([x, y2], true, true);
  series3.addPoint([x, y3], true, true);
  
  initiVal++;
}
```

But even if data is dynamically assigned to y axis values in each series, they do not update as expected in the chart. This is how the charts looks after the 6th second/instance when data needs to dynamically update in the chart.

[image]

Comment: Hi @Ishara Amarasekera, This problem looks very strange. Maybe the data you provide is in the wrong format or you may be modifying your data by accident.

Comment: @ppotaczek That's exactly what I thought but I still cannot figure out why and when it happens. Because when I log the dataArray inside the updateHighChart() function I can see the correct data has passed in a particular instance. Even the y values seems to hold the correct data when I log them in the console. This issue seems to arise inside the addPoint() method.

Comment: Did you try to use a browser `debugger` to follow the code operation?

Comment: @ppotaczek Thank you so much for your insight. I just resolved my issue. As  you mentioned in your previous comment, the issue was with the format of the data. Even if the data passed to the  updateHighChart() function seem to be in the correct format from outside, there was an issue with the format  of the data due to a small modification I do before I pass them to updateHighChart() function. So the chart was not able to identify them as data points to plot them in the chart. Hence, it keeps plotting zeros in y axis.